# Why is ROS not a real-time operating system?

Tags: ros

ROS is not real-time OS.
After reading the architecture of ROS, I am unable to realize why is ROS not real-time? What part of the architecture or what design decision is causing that?

Comment: Just as a reference; the same topic on ROS side http://answers.ros.org/question/134551/why-is-ros-not-real-time/

Answer (score 2):

Check out this website, http://www.control.com/thread/1026205354 you'll find your answer. The reason I directed you to this website is because ROS is an Operating System to provide Real-Time like operation but not truly. You can also call it as Pseudo-RTOS.

Comment: I am expecting an answer particular to the implementation of ROS.

Comment: Implementation as in ? :/

Comment: implementation as in, what particular part of ROS is the cause for it not being RT?

Comment: I found that it used TCP for communication and so is not RT

Comment: @Tvaṣṭā Thanks for the very informative link. However, is there a chance you can summarise the most salient points from that discussion? This helps prevent link rot and ensures people take the right answer away from this question.

Answer (score 2):

ROS isn't even an operating system, it's a framework and it's usually built on top of Ubuntu. First and foremost, it provides a clean way to write several modular programs with inputs and outputs and stitch them together at runtime.

There's no reason you can't run ROS inside a RTOS (however, it was developed on Ubuntu, so it will take effort to get it running on anything else.)